# keysSortedByValueUsingComparator in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to port some code over to swift. So far it's been fairly simple to do, but I'm stuck on keysSortedByValueUsingComparator. Can anyone give me a hand translating my objc code to swift?

I specifically do not understand how to translate this bit:

keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {}

stuff between the braces i understand

```
NSArray* matches = [startingExposureLookup keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber* x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fabs([obj1 floatValue] - totalExposureTimeInSecondsFloat)];
    NSNumber* y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fabs([obj2 floatValue] - totalExposureTimeInSecondsFloat)];
    return [x compare:y];
}];
```

Comment: Please show the translation attempts that you've already made.

Comment: Edit that into the question and explain the specific problem and what you don't understand.

Comment: You understand the stuff between the braces? Okay, one can understand the code, but none can understand why somebody wrote that code.

Comment: thats deep, your cool dude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` takes a closure (i.e. [NSComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparator)), whose type is defined as

`typealias NSComparator = (AnyObject!, AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult`

So you just need to pass in a closure that takes two values to compare and returns one of the enum values defined in [NSComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult).

Here is one example:

```
let dict: NSDictionary = ["b": 2, "a": 1]
dict.allKeys // ["b", "a"]

let keys = dict.keysSortedByValueUsingComparator {
    (obj1: AnyObject!, obj2: AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in
        let x = obj1 as NSNumber
        let y = obj2 as NSNumber
        return x.compare(y)
}

keys // ["a", "b"]
```

Note that Swift can [infer the types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID98) of a closure's parameters and the type of the return value, so you can omit the type declaration when you pass in the closure:

```
let keys = dict.keysSortedByValueUsingComparator {
    (obj1, obj2) in
        let x = obj1 as NSNumber
        let y = obj2 as NSNumber
        return x.compare(y)
}
```